# Eliminate polygons using attributes in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dissolve, eliminate

I've done an intersect of two polygon feature classes: one of neighborhoods and one with census block groups. I'm now trying to figure out how to merge the polygons smaller than a certain area with the neighboring polygon that shares the longest boundary, but prioritizing polygons that are within the same census block group. I've tried to use the "Eliminate" tool, but it doesn't let me specify attributes.

My next instinct was to use "dissolve" but I can't figure out a way to dissolve for each small polygon besides just selecting and dissolving manually.

Is there a tool in ArcGIS Pro that could help with this?

I know there's something called "Eliminate Sliver Polygons" in QGIS that makes this possible and I am looking for something similar in ArcGIS Pro.

The picture shows the selected polygons I want to eliminate and the symbology is by census block group.[image]

Comment: Do you know about this [tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

I think because you want to merge polygons based on both connectedness and attribute similarity, you should first use the [Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/h-how-dissolve-data-management-works.htm) tool, then [Explode](http://Explode) any multipart features if dissolve created any (which in your case, it should not.)

Remember that dissolve will use the common attributes you specify, and aggregate all those features which attribute match into a single (possibly multipart) feature whether they are touching or not!

So good news the touching ones get merged together, possible bad news if other disconnected polygons also match on neighboorhood and census block.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to start with :Polygon to Line" tool, because output edges will have enough info to complete your task. After deleting outer edges (LEFT_FID =-1) their table will look similar to:
[image]

Use joins between LEFT_FID/RIGHT_FID and OID of polygons to transfer census attributes to edge table:
[image]

Delete edges with different census attributes (LEFT_CENSUS <> RIGHT_CENSUS).
Do spatial join (share boundary) between remaining edges and selected polygons, making sure polygons have unique id:

[image]

**If number of lines in spatial join is greater than number of selected polygons, you'll need to sort them in descending(!) order by shape length and delete identical by polygon id.**

After that you can select polygons that share a boundary with spatial join and dissolve them to single parts (no attribute):

[image]

I'll leave it to you how to transfer parent attribute(s) to dissolved table. I'd use inside centroids of non-selected polygons and a couple of spatial joins.

Comment: Automating this procedure, while tedious, would make a useful tool if you have to do this several times!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have prematurely excluded the [Eliminate (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate.htm) tool from providing your solution because it:

> Eliminates polygons by merging them with neighboring polygons that
> have the largest area or the longest shared border.

The part of the documentation that I think you may have overlooked is:

> Features that will be eliminated are determined by a selection applied
> to a polygon layer. The selection must be determined in a previous
> step using the [Select Layer by Attribute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) tool ...

Unfortunately, I cannot test this because I do not have the required Advance level license to run that tool.

Comment: Hi! I tried this, but the eliminate tool didn't allow me to merge BY attribute. So even though I was able to select by attributes for the polygons I wanted to eliminate, I still couldn't figure out a way to ensure that the eliminate tool merges them with a nearby polygon that has the same block group value AND shares the longest common boundary. Thanks for the suggestion though!